# NMEA (GPS) sentence to a map location

Tags: gps, nmea

I'm having a hard time understanding how to see on a map the location given to me by some location NMEA sentence:

foe example: given the sentence

```
$GPRMC,225446,A,4916.45,N,12311.12,W,000.5,054.7,191194,020.3,E*68
```

where and what information do I type, to see this location on a map?

Comment: What language or platform are you trying to do this in?  See http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm#RMC for the format.  The coordinates in your example are approximately 49.16 N, 123.11 W.

Comment: I write in c++, but I dont see hoe it matters... and how do I see this location on a map? thanks

Comment: Go to Google Maps and enter "49.16 N, 123.11 W" in the search box.

Comment: Oh never mond.. I just need to entry those parameters into some mapping site. thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just put those params into 
http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/

Answer (score 30):

It is in `ddmm.mmmm` format for latitude and in `dddmm.mmmm` for longitude

to convert it into dd.dddd format you will need to do

```
dd + mm.mmmm/60 for latitude
ddd + mm.mmmm/60 for longitude
```

in your case

```
4916.45,N,12311.12,W
```

will be

```
49 + (16.45/60) = 49.2741 N
123 + (11.12/60) = 123.1853 W
```

simply put (49.2741 N 123.1853 W) on google maps to see the location

Answer (score 0):

go to this website:
https://www.gpsvisualizer.com

click on "Plot data points"

Now you will see text box. copy your NMEA strings there. it will display the positions on the map